# Character to string . confused

Tags: c#, char

I'm currently learning C#.

a little bit confused about convertion

especially converting character to string;

The code isn't working.

this line : `Console.WriteLine(Char.ToString(i));`

is converting a character to string possible?
i just used character because its a letter choices. if i use a string it will be easy for me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SwitchStatement.Example
{
class SwitchSt
{
    static void Main()
    {
        char i;
        Console.WriteLine("Who is the current President of the United States?");
        Console.WriteLine("\nA.) Barack Obama\n" 
                       +  "B.) George Bush\n"
                       +  "C.) Bill Gates\n"
                       );

        Console.Write("Type the letter of your answer : ");
        Console.ReadLine(Char.ToString(i));
        switch(i)
        {
            case 'a' :
                     break;
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to read something from the console? Printing `i` doesn't make sense as it is not assigned any value.

Comment: It would be helpful to mention the exact error message you got instead of only saying: "It doesn't work".

Comment: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider' C:\Users\Login Here\Documents\Programming\Visual C#\SwitchStatement\SwitchStatement\Example\SwitchSt.cs 27 45 SwitchStatement

Comment: I don't think you're actually compiling anything, are you copying homework from someone?

Comment: Im compiling here. still a new programmer learning. i Already updated the code. its Console.ReadLine(Char.ToString(i)); not WriteLine im requesting an input from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you'll need to assign or prompt the user for the char before displaying it. You'll receive the error:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'i'

In addition to static `Char.ToString(ch)`, it is more common to convert a char to a String, using the variable instance `i`.

```
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
```

However, there is also an [overload of `WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/406f266x(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes a char directly:

```
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Which IMO would be preferable as it has the least `ceremony` surrounding the char.

**Edit**

Use one of the `Console.Read*` methods to read the char. Here's [`Console.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that as `Read` returns an int, you'll need to cast to a `char`.

```
Console.Write("Type the letter of your answer : ");
char i = (char)Console.Read();
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Final point - many will find the use of `i` for a char surprising, as `i,j + k` are typically used for integers, especially counters. Possibly rename `char i` to `char ch` or similar?

Comment: i mean not Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()); . i mean Console.ReadLine.. i need and input from the user

Comment: THANKS! i need to learn more about casting.  What is the purpose of this line Console.WriteLine(Char.ToString(i)); i eraser that however my problem is solved and still working without it. it just print the letter that i requested from the user again.

Comment: That line just echoes the same character that has been entered to the Console screen.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use a pre-defined method `ToString()` for this , like this example below ;

```
char ch = 'a';   

Console.WriteLine(ch.ToString());       // Output: "a"
```

To read input char

```
Console.Write("Enter a alphabet: ");
char a = (char)Console.Read();
  Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
  age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 //Show the details you typed
        Console.WriteLine("your letter is {0}.", a.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Age is {0}.", age);
```

Comment: i already updated the code. i mean i want to get an input from the user. i just declared char i; without a value.